# What does href="#_self" mean?

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen this here and there, but can't find any information regarding this "thing".
Can anyone please provide us some sort of info regarding the `#_self` propose ?

Comment: hash values maybe? or possibly a trigger/value used for a jquery pluggin? can you post an example?

Comment: if the question is rephrased as "what does href="#id" mean?" then it becomes apparent that it is trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<a href="#_self">` will jump to an element with the id of `_self` in the current page.

For instance, further below the page, there's a `<p>` element that looks like this:

```
<p id="_self"> ... </p>
```

It's pretty weird to have an ID with that name though, so probably a decoy anchor link for a `jQuery` function.